# how to set active class to nav menu from bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm new to the bootstrap. Using their navigation menus. I'm trying to set the active class to the selected menu. my menu is -

```
<li class="nav-parent">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>Information</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-children">
        <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('#');?>">
                                                    Terms & Condition
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('#');?>">
                                                    Privacy & Policy
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('#');?>">
                                                    About Us
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I tried the following thing after googling on this that I have to set the active class on each page from the menu like as--

```
<script>
            $('li a').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('li a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class: active to the li element

```
<li class="active">Selected Li</li>
```